# why the result is always 101? I think the result should be random since is not thread safe

Tags: java, concurrency

why the result is always 101? 
 I think the result should be random since is shareVar not thread safe

```
public class ThreadQuestion
{  
    public static  int shareVar = 1; 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  
    {  
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);  
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)  
        {  
            threadPool.execute(new Runnable()  
            {  
                @Override  
                public void run()   
                {  
                        shareVar++;  
                }  
            });  
        }  
        //wait for other thread finish
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("shareVar is " + shareVar );  
        threadPool.shutdown();  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your concurrent tasks run practically sequential because CPU extremely fast so your task(increment) will run really quick. Your loop execute a bit slower so when you add new task old task will be already executed.  Moreover concurrency it's always about theory of chances and 100 it's a small value for getting glitches for this short task.

You should expand loop to bigger value for example to 10000 or even 10000 or just put a tiny delay in your code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    threadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
                shareVar++;
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ThreadQuestion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

in this case you'll really try to run several threads in the same time and result will change from 101 to about a hundred.